# AllowFullScrren attribute for inserting flash

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, tinymce

I created a web form with TinyMCE editor in asp.net. I configured the following TinyMCE editor.

```
tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode: "specific_textareas",
        editor_selector: "mceEditor",
        theme: "advanced",
        media_strict: false,
        file_browser_callback: 'myFileBrowser',
        plugins: "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave",
        setup: function(ed) {
            ed.onSubmit.add(function(ed) {
                ed.save();
            });
        },

        // Theme options 
        theme_advanced_buttons1: "newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4: "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak,restoredraft",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing: true,

        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS) 
        content_css: "css/content.css",

        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs 
        template_external_list_url: "lists/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url: "lists/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url: "lists/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url: "lists/media_list.js",

        // Style formats 
        style_formats: [
            { title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b' },
            { title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: { color: '#ff0000'} },
            { title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: { color: '#ff0000'} },
            { title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1' },
            { title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2' },
            { title: 'Table styles' },
            { title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1' }
        ]

    });
    function myFileBrowser(field_name, url, type, win) {
        //alert("Field_Name: " + field_name + "nURL: " + url + "nType: " + type + "nWin: " + win); // debug/testing

        var cmsURL = 'http://www.mywebsite.com';    // script URL - use an absolute path!
        if (cmsURL.indexOf("?") < 0) {
            //add the type as the only query parameter
            cmsURL = cmsURL + "?FileType=";
        }
        else {
            //add the type as an additional query parameter
            cmsURL = cmsURL + "&FileType=";
        }

        if (type == 'image') {
            cmsURL = cmsURL + 'jpg,jpeg,png.bmp';
        } else if (type == 'media') {
            cmsURL = cmsURL + 'swf,flv';
        } else {
            cmsURL = cmsURL + 'All';
        }

        tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
            file: cmsURL,
            title: 'File Browser',
            width: '400',  // Your dimensions may differ - toy around with them!
            height: '500',
            resizable: 'yes',
            inline: "yes",  // This parameter will cause the Popup window internal 
            close_previous: "no"
        }, {
            window: win,
            input: field_name
        });
        return false;
    }

<textarea id="TinyMCEEditor" name="TinyMCEEditor" class="mceEditor" rows="15" cols="80" runat="server"></textarea>
```

And then I tested this. It is ok. When I clicked media button and insert flash, I didn't find allowfullscreen option(see following figure).

[image]

And I tried to type allowfullscreen attribute manually at source tag. But it didn't approve. I want to add allowfullscreen attribute. How can I do this? please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you will have to add "allowfullscreen" as an attribute of your desired html element tag to your [valid_elements](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=tinymce%20valid_elements&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_elements&ei=ZyOlTo72E4ar-QaIy82aBA&usg=AFQjCNHwEo5B454vhfAv9UB8B2a7xHSVsw&cad=rja) setting of tinymce.